# Guest Entries - How I can send message to user after saving form information

Tags: plugin-guestentries

I use Guest Entries plugin to add information, and I need to send some message to user who filled the form to email. Can you show me an example of how I can do this?

Comment: Is this Guest Entries 1 for Craft 2 or Guest Entries 2 for Craft 3?

Comment: it is Guest Entries 2 for Craft 3

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a small plugin that listened to the Guest Entries [afterSaveEntry](https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries#the-aftersaveentry-event) event.

The logic would look something like this:

```
use craft\guestentries\controllers\SaveController;
use craft\guestentries\events\SaveEvent;
use yii\base\Event;

// ...

Event::on(SaveController::class, SaveController::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ENTRY, function(SaveEvent $e) {
    // Grab the entry
    $entry = $e->entry;

    // Assuming `toEmail` is a custom field on the entry.
    Craft::$app->getMailer()->compose()
        ->setSubject('Thanks for your submission!')
        ->setTextBody('You are amazing.')
        ->setTo($entry->toEmail)
        ->send();
});
```

You can generate Craft 3 boilerplate plugin code using [https://pluginfactory.io/](https://pluginfactory.io) and the official Craft 3 Plugin docs are here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html